# Is it possible to interrupt installation procedure at power on

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, install

My friend is bringing back a new Macbook Air from abroad to the UK for me. [New rules](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-28226552) have been put in place

> to power up electronic devices in hand luggage as part of new security measures introduced at UK airports

so it's possible that my friend will have to charge the laptop and then power it on at the security gates. The first power on will (possibly) start the install procedure - I don't know, I haven't run an install on a Macbook for a few years - and I'd like to know if it will be a problem for the friend or the laptop to do a quick power on and then close down the laptop?

Any help or insight with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is.

If you quit the installer when it starts, it will shut down the computer, and next time it starts up it will run the installer from the start again.